# Changing permalink from /postname/ to category/postname/

Tags: categories, permalinks, redirect, tags

I have a website where it consists more than 800 posts, At present my permalinks structure is `/%postname%/`, but due to some reasons I want to change it to `/%category%/%postname%/`

I have implemented the redirect plugins and it is working well, but I need to know whether it will harm my website because I need best SEO to my website and which is already there, So in case if I change this whether it will leads to any problems like Duplicate Contents.

Because in some of my old posts there more than 2 categories and some posts contains more than 6 tags will the google consider it as duplicate contents if yes then how can I solve this which is the best idea and shortcut way to do is?

I thought of deleting the tags and categories straight away in the `wp_term_relationships` table in WordPress by conditioning if there are more tags or more categories cut down to single or two in the table,  but I feared that whether it will brings any problem.

Comment: You can use [wp_rewrite](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Rewrite) to do that with ease :)

Answer (score 1):

**Redirect-** If you did a proper redirect, there is no content on the pages you're redirecting from. So there's no issue with the content being duplicate.

**Tags/Categories-** If the categories and tags serve a function and add value, then they're not really duplicate content. So choose categories and tags wisely. I wouldn't delete old ones because there might be links to them, so then you'll be making even more problems.

Answer (score 0):

noone likes to change urls - it's an extra headache. However, google tries to be liberal, so it tries best, to accomodify your changes and not to loose your SEO, and if you  redirect 301, then everything  should be ok, however i think so. Of course, you should make redirection, because duplicate content is very very bad.

Comment: Then what about the duplicate contents

Answer (score 0):

WordPress will automatically do 301 redirects, since post name is unique.
Check within your browser (F12 - Network) - see when you type the old address, even without the plugin it will do the job.

Fixing all the internal links should be done, so the website doesn't work using redirects for each internal link click.

If clicking a tag, or a category, gives a list of post excerpts, you shouldn't have any duplicate content problems.

Either way, since (if) 301 redirects are done properly (WP does it automatically) there should be no loss in ranking, nor should it affect SEO.

My tests with WP auto redirects (with screenshots):
https://io.bikegremlin.com/6768/permalink-change/#5

Another thing to note: if one post is within 2, or more categories, when opened, it will show only the firstly created category in its url. That is, if you have:

post1, within category1 and category2.
And you open: yourwebsite/category2/, then click on the post1 link. The URL you will go to will be:
yourwebsite/category1/post1, even though you started from within category2.

Hence, it could be confusing to visitors if you place one post within more than one category.